# Resume a MongoDB Atlas cluster with connection URL

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have lost access to the google account which was connected to my mongodb atlas account. I want to access and download the data that was stored in that mongodb instance. I have the connection URI to the instance. The cluster has paused and I can not access the data with just the connection URI.

Earlier I would just log in and resume the cluster but now that I can not log in I do not know what to do. I have tried connecting using the connection URI but the connection just times out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.